# Is positive linear combination closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $v_1 , v_2 ,...,v_n $ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$.
I think that following  subset of   $\mathbb{R}^m$ is closed
$$Q = \{x \in  \mathbb{R}^m  : x = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i v_i \ ,\ \lambda_i \geq 0   \}$$
If I look at the complement that doesn't help me a lot.
Any idea or hint would be great.

Comment: Assuming you're using the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^m$, I think this might be possible if you use the characterization of closed as "every convergent sequence in $Q$ has its limit in $Q$".

Comment: The set $Q$ is closed, and moreover is convex - it is the set of conic combinations of the $v_i$, known as a *cone*.

Comment: For a proof that this set is closed, check the section about "Finitely Generated Cones" in these notes: https://pages.wustl.edu/files/pages/imce/nachbar/conesrn.pdf

Comment: @kamills Could you elobarate your answer please?